# Should we change the truth table for the material conditional?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Having studied logic, I still cannot understand the conditional. At first, it was because (as with most things I learn) it was a problem with my understanding. I now believe it is because there is an actual problem not properly understood.

So, as you know, the conditional assesses the statement 'If A then B'. Now, I strongly presume that this means if A is *true*, because in a way you could say if A is *false* you're still considering the value of A, so that even if A is false it still means 'if A'. Though from what i've read the statement only holds if A is true. After All, surely 'if A' ≠ 'if not A'.

Ok sweet, lets right down the truth table:

```
A    B   Value
______    
1    1:    T
1    0:    F
0    1:
0    0:
```

So far i've only done half the truth table. That half is within the bounds that we know that A is true.

Why haven't I completed the other half? Well, the truth value refers to the statement '*if* A *then* B', we do not know what happens when A does *not* occur.

To resolve this, logicians have chosen to set the value of the proposition  to be true for when A is not true by default. Now, it *can't* be the case that all factors are held constant (except A, of course), for when A is false, otherwise it would literally be impossible for B to be occur and not occur given the exact same conditions.

So, by deduction, we *have* to consider the fact that the state of the world is different for when where A is false yet B is true, and for when A is still false yet B is also false.

In doing so, this means that if A is false yet B is still true, then something tells us that there are other causes which lead to B. Once again however, the condition is 'if A then B', not 'if A and possibly some other factor then B', or, where X is some arbitrary factor, 'if A or X then B'= '(A+X) -> B'.

So the main problem I have here, is that we are trying to assign a truth value for other conditions that we initially set ourselves, which I think is bad logic. I strongly believe we should just consider the truth value for where A is false to be unknown.

If we don't, then would we not have to accept that what we're really saying is by 'If A, then B' is actually 'If A or some other unknown factor X, then B'?

The issue in the conditional crosses over to other areas as well. For e.g, take the case 'A unless B' = ~B -> A = A V B.

However, if B occurs, and A still occurs despite the fact B still occurs, then this is still a true statement. This means that 'A unless B' is NOT saying that A won't occur even IF B occurs.

Comment: Short answer: **NO**.

Comment: Long answer: you can read many post on this site discussing the truth-functional definition of the so-called "material implication". See at least [material implication](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918839/material-implication) or  [when is implication true ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556298/when-is-implication-true).

Comment: The truth table describes the connective we need in order to make mathematics work. _Calling_ this connective "implication" or "if-then" is just a practical convention, because the everyday meaning of those words is _close enough_ to the truth table we want to be useful mnemonics.

Comment: Henning Makholm -> But if we assume that B is true given A is false, then if it's the case that B is true iff A is true (and we don't know this), then surely our initial assumption would of been wrong. It doesn't seem like a good way to go. Plus, mathematics is primarily about deductive reasoning, so how is it that B could both occur and not occur given the absence of A when using deductive arguments?

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA right 'because I said so' is a strong premise for what is simultaneously your conclusion.

Comment: "mathematics is primarily about deductive reasoning": PERFECT ! and this is why truth-functional implication fits well. Mathematics is "proving theorems from axioms" and very seldom we are interested to derive consequences from false premises.

Comment: See also the post [implications and ordinary language](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718925/implications-and-ordinary-language)

Comment: The translation of "if $A$, then $B$" in logic with the *material conditional* : $\to$ does not assume that there is a "causal relation" linking $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39901/discussion-between-user108262-and-mauro-allegranza).

Comment: You can see [Paradoxes of material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication) and [Conditionals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/): you are **not** alone in having troubles with material implication. As you can see, tehre are many interesting proposals for "better" translations of "if___, then___". But they needs to leave the truth-functional definition of the conditional. What does not work is to stay with the truth-functional def of connectives changing only the truth-table for $\to$.

Comment: @  Mauro ALLEGRANZA Oh, well that's, that's definitely something. Thanks. By the way I think I may have misread your tone.

Comment: See my answer to as similar question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551320/understanding-vacuously-true-truth-table/1551525#1551525

Answer (score 1):

Material implication is good for statements like, "if $x$ is rational, then $x^2$ is rational" -- which is a statement that we would like to think of as true, and which we logically render as
$$
\forall x\in \mathbb R(x \in \mathbb Q \to x^2 \in \mathbb Q).
$$
We want the inner statement to be true for any $x$. In particular, we want it to be true for $\sqrt 2$, where the antecedent is false while the consequent is true. Edit: and we want it to be true for $\sqrt[4]2$, where both the antecedent and the consequent are false.

Comment: If A = 2(1/2) and B = 2, then saying that A = 0 and B = 1, is true, yes. However, A = 0 and B = 0, is false, though interpreted as also true. How can that be right? It's like am the only one that has a problem with that :/

Comment: You agree that my sentence should be true, right? So the part in parentheses should be true for all $x$? In particular, it should be true for $x=\sqrt[4]2$? Which of these statements do you disagree with?

Comment: Well, if x is x is 2^(1/2), then saying that 2(1/2)^2 does not lead to a rational number, is false. However, isn't this interpreted as true given the conditional statement?

Comment: I am talking about the quartic root of 2, not the square root.

Comment: But if your talking about the quadratic root, then setting A to false and B true is not correct either. The thing is, is that x^2, no matter what it is, can't be both rational and irrational. So where A is false, the statement x^2 is rational (B is true) and x^2 is not rational (B is false) can't BOTH be true. Something has to give.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Well, the statement 'if x is rational, then x^2 is rational' follows the logical form if A thus B. So if both A and B are false, this is interpreted as a true statement. Lets say x is 2(1/2) = sqrt(2). Saying that both A and B are false, is saying x^(1/2) is irrational, and that 2^(1/2)^2 is also irrational, which is false, but yet still stands as a logically correct argument.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are false, then indeed $A \to B$ is true. However, $x = \sqrt 2$ in the above sentence is not an example of that. Because then $B$, which says $x^2 = 2 \in \mathbb Q$ is true. However, if $x = \sqrt[4]2$, then $A$, which says $x \in \mathbb Q$, is false, and $B$, which says $x^2 = \sqrt2 \in \mathbb Q$, is also false. And we want $A \to B$ to be true in order for the entire sentence $\forall x \in \mathbb R(x \in \mathbb Q \to x^2 \in \mathbb Q)$ to be true. Thus, false $\to$ false should be true.

Answer (score 1):

According to your table, (P -> P) is not a tautology, because the fourth row is left blank.  It doesn't make much sense to say that (P -> P) is not a tautology.

According to your table also, (P -> (Q -> P)) is not a tautology.  Given that (P -> P) is a tautology, (0 -> 0) = 1.  So, (0 -> (0 -> 0)) = (0 -> 1) which remains indeterminate and thus (P -> (Q -> P)) is not a tautology.  If (P -> (Q -> P)) is not a tautology, then you can't start with an assumption A, derive a conclusion C, and then infer that (A -> C), because you can only do that when a system either assumes the rule of conditional introduction (which I more-or-less just said) or has enough to prove the deduction meta-theorem which implies that (P -> (Q -> P)) is a tautology (so long as the system is sound).  If (0 -> 1) = 0, then (P -> (Q -> P)) is not a tautology.  That again, implies that you can't start with an assumption A, derive a conclusion C, and then infer that (A -> C).  Consequently, so long as you want to have the ability to start with an assumption A, derive a conclusion C, and then infer that (A -> C), it holds that (0 -> 1) = 1, and thus the table for the material conditional holds.

So, no, the truth table for the material conditional should remain as it stands.

Comment: I don't see what you by (P -> P) is not a tautology, though. If you have one variable then wouldn't it just be a 2 bit truth table? For a conditional, wouldn't you need to consider the effect one variable has on another?

Comment: @user108262 No, you don't consider the effects of one variable on another, because variables don't have effects on each other.  The truth table for (P -> P) is two lines, yes.  It entails that (0 -> 0) = 1 and (1 -> 1) = 1.

Comment: Oh right sorry, I mean propositions. And yes, it would imply 0 -> 0 = 1, but only it also implies 0 ->0 = 0, which is impossible, if, 0 -> 0 =1. But of course 0 -> 0 must = 1, it's just that, when those truth values are assigned to propositions, 0 would mean 'if not P', but we only know what happens 'if P' occurs, right?

Comment: @user108262 Propositions don't have effects.  Propositions consist of statements.  Statements assert, deny, describe, etc.  They do not act, and thus cannot cause anything, and consequently don't have effects.

Comment: Yes I know, my mistake. I did mean propositions though. That is, when I said variables I had the idea of a proposition in my mind. But yes, variable was definitely the wrong term.